# codeigniter url causing error in removing index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp, teamviewer

i have posted question yesterday about removing index dot php from codeigniter path but problem not solved... so can any one come on to team viewer and solve my problem...? thanks in anticipation

my .htaccess in root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did you enable rewrite mode on your web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your .htaccess file to that directory where index.php exists and remove it from application directory if exists.

Then paste following code in .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I assume you already perform the other steps which includes turn on the rewrite engine in WAMP and in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also set

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: tried but errorr.......................................................................................     Not Found

The requested URL /si/public/signup was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: how to turn on the rewrite engine in WAMP

Comment: click: **WAMP icon->Apache->Apache modules->chose rewrite_module**

and **do restart for all services**

Comment: Let me know if it helps.